# How does f(s(s(s(s(s(s(1)))))),C) work on Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I am practicing from textbook and cannot find the reason when I see the result.

On prolog data base, it shows

```
f(1,one).
f(s(1),two).
f(s(s(1)),three).
f(s(s(s(X))),N) :- f(X,N).
```

When I run the program with

```
f(s(s(s(s(s(s(1)))))),C).
```

The response of program is "C = one."

How does it work?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: You won't like it, but the answer is: "It works by SLD resolution"

Comment: Have you tried using `trace`? It gives you some detail on what happens when executing a query. But maybe this will help: On the query, Prolog will try to match `f(s(s(s(s(s(s(1)))))),C).` to the head of one of your clauses or a fact. It will match `f(s(s(s(X))),N)` if `X = s(s(s(1)))` and `C = N`. So follow it from there to see how deep the rabbit hole goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prolog is very simple. Its programs consist of rules of the form

```erlang
to_prove_this :- must_prove_this, and_this.          % and perhaps also,
to_prove_this :- must_otherwise_prove_this, and_this_too.
```

So your program just means

```
1. to prove `f( 1, one)` :- there's no need to prove anything more.
2. to prove `f( s(1), two)` :- there's no need to prove anything more.
3. to prove `f( s(s(1)), three)` :- there's no need to prove anything more.
4. to prove `f( s(s(s(X))), N)` :- must prove `f( X, N)`.
```

So you start with

```
to prove:    f( s(s(s(s(s(s(1)))))), C).
```

Can  rule `1.` be used?

```
| Is `f( s(s(s(s(s(s(1)))))), C)` similar to `f(1,one)`?  
| | Is `f` similar to `f`?  
| | -- Yes.  
| | Is `s(s(s(s(s(s(1))))))` similar to `1`?  
| | -- No.  
| -- No, `f( s(s(s(s(s(s(1)))))), C)` and `f(1,one)` are not similar.  
-- No, the rule 1. can't be used.
```

Can rule `2.` be used?

```
| Is `f( s(s(s(s(s(s(1)))))), C)` similar to `f(s(1),two)`?  
. . . . .  
. . . . .  
. . . . .
```

Can rule `4.` be used?

```
| Is `f( s(s(s(s(s(s(1)))))), C)` similar to `f(s(s(s(X))),N)`?  
| | Is `f` similar to `f`?  
| | -- Yes.  
| | Is `s(s(s(s(s(s(1))))))` similar to `s(s(s(X)))`?  
| | | Is `s(s(s(s(s(1)))))` similar to `s(s(X))`?  
| | | | Is `s(s(s(s(1))))` similar to `s(X)`?  
| | | | | Is `s(s(s(1)))` similar to `X`?  
| | | | | -- Yes,                            with `X = s(s(s(1)))`.  
| | Is `C` similar to `N`?  
| | -- Yes,                                  with `C = N`.  
| -- Yes, it is similar,                     with `X = s(s(s(1)))` and `C = N`.  
-- Yes, it can be used,                      with `X = s(s(s(1)))` and `C = N`.
```

This means, we need to prove `f(X,N)` now, with `X = s(s(s(1)))` and `C = N`.
This means, we need to prove `f(X1,N1)` now, with `X1 = s(s(s(1)))` and `C = N1`.
This means, we need to prove `f( s(s(s(1))), C )` now.

Can rule `1.` be used?

```
. . . .  
. . . .  
. . . .
```

This means, we need to prove `f(X,N)` now, with `X = 1` and `C = N`.
This means, we need to prove `f(X2,N2)` now, with `X2 = 1` and `C = N2`.
This means, we need to prove `f( 1, C )` now.

Can rule `1.` be used *now*?

Comment: Thanks Will Ness for helping me to understand. I still have a doubt that

rule 1 : f( 1, one)

because X = s(s(s(1))) and this X is not equal to 1 - why can we use this rule? Do I need to understand more about basic syntax?

Comment: to prove `f( s(s(s(s(s(s(1)))))), C)` rule 4 fits, where we need to prove `f( s(s(s(1))), C)`; and to prove that, rule 4 fits again, where we still need to prove `f( 1, C)`. and for that, rule 1 fits. that's it. Of course my answer here didn't explain *all* of Prolog. :) You need to study more tutorials for that (or  ask more focused, specific, narrow questions on SO) :)

Comment: first of all you need to understand structure of the terms - atoms, numbers, logical variables, compound terms (like `f(a,b,c,...n)`). Then you need to understand the matching (unification) of these terms (what I called "being similar"): 1 and 1 match, 1 and 2 don't; `s(1)` and `s(X)` match *if* `X` and `1` match; `s(1)` and q(X)` never match; etc. *Then*  do some examples like here, by hand. To use a rule, its *head* (the part before `:-`) must match your *goal*, and if to does match - possibly with some substitutions - the body of that rule needs to be proven, with those same substitutions.

Comment: @NontawatPattanajak the query eventually reduces to the `f(1, one)` case via recursion. You should try the `trace` like I suggested in my first comment to your question.

Comment: @lurker Thanks for your suggestion. This is what I run for trace.    
  'Call: (9) f(s(s(s(s(s(s(1)))))), _3728) ? creep
   Call: (10) f(s(s(s(1))), _3728) ? creep
   Call: (11) f(1, _3728) ? creep
   Exit: (11) f(1, one) ? creep
   Exit: (10) f(s(s(s(1))), one) ? creep
   Exit: (9) f(s(s(s(s(s(s(1)))))), one) ? creep
C = one.'

Comment: @NontawatPattanajak looks like a reasonable trace. It shows each step along the way for unification of successive recursive queries to facts and rules. So that should help.